# Reuse small html page fragment template

Tags: html, css, templates, jekyll

I have an order information html template to user in multiple pages inside my website using Jekyll

```
<div class="ccpanel">
    {% include order_info.html %}
</div>
```

In my order_info.html fragment template, I have 5 fields.

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label>First Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="First Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label>Last Name</label>
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label>Order ID</label>
            <input class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label>Order Description</label>
            <input class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label>Order Note</label>
            <input class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have some pages that need to display all 5 fields in the order_info.html which works fine but I also have some pages that only need to display 3 fields in the order_info.html.

How can I reuse the order_info.html template for all pages? Or do I have to create another template of order info with 3 fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could pass a variable to the template, and do an if condition inside

```
{% include order_info.html fields=3 %}
```

Then inside

```
{% if include.fields == 3 %}
{% endif %}
```